# Where can I get a PEM (private) key?

Tags: java, saml, assertion, opensaml

I am working on IdP-initiated SAML response for Salesforce and need your help.

I was working with the code and found that I need a .pem (private) key.

```
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)   ks.getEntry("alias", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));
PrivateKey pk = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
```

The PEM key will be used to sign my response signature. Where can I get a .pem key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -subj ‘/C=US/ST=CA/L=San Mateo/CN=www.appirio.com’ -keyout key-mycompanyrsa.pem -out cert-mycompanyrsa.pem
```

More info:
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/06/using-rsa-sha1-with-salesforce-crypto-class/

Comment: Thanks. I got private key and certificate. How can I add both in the keystore *.jks

Comment: For the openssl query above: use double quotes instead of single quotes(if single quotes did not work).